# Attempted to call method "fromJsonString" on class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse"

Tags: php, json, symfony

I am attempting to use json response in symfony controller. I have imported this as a resource in the controller as shown

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

I trying to use the json response here

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
        $json = $serializer->serialize($idata, 'json');
        $response = JsonResponse::fromJsonString($json); //this is the error line
```

> Attempted to call method "fromJsonString" on class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse" in xxxx line 180

Why am I getting this error

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of symfony you use but in newer version you don't need to import the class. If you have an action in your controller you can use it like this:

```
return $this->json(['key' => 'value'];
```

you can find an example here.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#returning-json-response

**For older versions:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

$json = json_encode($idata);
return JsonResponse::fromJsonString($json);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response

You should test to encode you json data with the normal php function.

Comment: Based on your posts, I did this

Comment: $response = $this->json([$response => $json]);
        return $response;

Comment: Getting this error>>> Attempted to call method "json" on class

Comment: Which symfony version do you use?

Comment: Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.5.6